# Stop scrolling in a listview

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have in my activity a listview and an imagebutton.
When I click the imagebutton I want to go to a specific position in the list (I do this by calling: setSelection(int position) on the list.
The problem occurs when the user flings the listview and then clicks the imagebutton.
The list goes to the specified position but continues scrolling.

eg. when I go into fling mode, click the button, then I go to the fourth position, but the listview keeps scrolling, so I end up with a selection of 25

Answer (score 8):

I have write simple method to stop scoll ListView using reflection.

```
private void stopScroll(AbsListView view)
{
    try
    {
        Field field = android.widget.AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mFlingRunnable");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object flingRunnable = field.get(view);
        if (flingRunnable != null)
        {
            Method method = Class.forName("android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable").getDeclaredMethod("endFling");
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(flingRunnable);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Just call stopScroll(myListView); when you need to stop scroll.

Answer (score 8):

```
// Stop scrolling
smoothScrollBy(0, 0);
```

Internally this will call the method that @Nik is trying to reflect.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
listView.smoothScrollBy(0, 0); // to stop the scrolling.
// followed by
listView.setSelection(position) // to move to the specific position.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a method for manual scrolling 
you can call listview.scrollTo(int, int);
But I do not have idea how can you calculate how much to scroll, I mean how to calculate the arguments of the method. Also this doesn't stop scrolling it just positions you at a specific place and then stop scrolling, so you might have a little flicker...
If doesn't solve you problem at list will give some hints.

[more](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) about the method

Comment: from what I understand the scrollTo method is not really for scrolling inside a listview, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: well I used the scrollTo method for example to scroll the list to the middle, or let say to scroll little bit down like functionality they use in the browsers to scroll as much as the height of the address bar, so when you open a link you get full screen of the content and if you want to see the address bar you have to scroll little upper . . . open tho browser and you will get what I want to say

Answer (score 0):

I would try calling `ListView.smoothScrollToPosition(int position)` to scroll back to the right position. As all the gui stuff is done in one thread I think there's little chance to really stop the scrolling on button press, so the easiest would be scrolling back (which might even be a nice gui effect too).

Comment: I've already tried this and this works, but I don't want to let the user wait for 10seconds to get to the right position in the list

Answer (score -2):

did you try `listView.clearAnimation()` ? it might work