# Scene Transition Flicker

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a simple view containing a `scene root` `FrameLayout`, `ListView` and a couple of buttons on the bottom.

`scene root` is used to load and show different scenes, the size changes dynamically depending on the current `scene`. `ListView` is set to `match_parent` in both directions and is positioned behind `scene root`.

Here's the issue:

If I start a transition using the buttons on the bottom everything works ok, no problem, magic. However, if I transition (✝) to a different scene while scrolling (✝✝) the transition seems to flicker before starting.

It almost looks like the rendering engine fails to load the first frame of the animation before the `ListView` invalidates the hierarchy due to scrolling.

Thanks for the help ;)

✝ `TransitionManager.go(Scene, Transition)`

✝✝ I've added a couple of methods to the `ListView` to allow that

Comment: it would help if there is some codes to start off with

Comment: can you please add some piece of your code

Answer (score 2):

All the Google apps that use Scene Transition that I've seen transit from some item in a `ListView` to its detail `Activity`. Since `ListView` has the convenient behavior of immediately stop the scrolling when touched, such a transition doesn't produce flickering.

So it appears the best thing to do may be to programmatically stop the scrolling before transiting to the new `Activity`, which is accomplished by the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819145/stop-scrolling-in-a-listview).